# How to apply condition on jquery blur event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to check if user tab on this input then variable a = student_id and if user tab on this input then variable a = book_id. is this possible. For example:-

Is this possible that if user tab on book id input field then alert book or if user tab on student_id field then it alert student id

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#stu_id").blur()) {
    var id = $("#stu_id").val();
  } else if ($("#book_id).blur()){
    var id = $("#book_id").val();
  }
  $(id).blur(function() {
    // ajax code
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stu_id" id="stu_id">
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="stu_name">
<input type="text" name="book_id" id="book_id">
<input type="text" name="book_name" id="book_name">
```

Comment: blur means loosing focus on input. Why do you use blur instead of focus event?

Comment: If you mean by "to tab" to specifically press the tab key, you should listen to `keydown` or `keyup` events instead. Your question is a bit unclear about this too: do you want the alert to happen when entering the inputs, or leaving them?

Comment: Also note that your snippet is missing a closing quote on one of the selectors in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your question but it seems you are using blur the wrong way. Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input').blur(function(e){
       var val = $(this).val()
       console.log(val)
       //Ajax code here
   
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stu_id" id="stu_id">
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="stu_name">
<input type="text" name="book_id" id="book_id">
<input type="text" name="book_name" id="book_name">
```

Comment: heartly Thank you all for supporting me, again thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `focus` event for the target inputs you want to get the `id` property of.

When you loose focus on them (here, you may have hit submit or selected another input) then the `blur` event on that target input element is triggered (here, you may want to submit the value to a server-side script via ajax).

```html
<input type="text" name="stu_id" id="stu_id">
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="stu_name">
<input type="text" name="book_id" id="book_id">
<input type="text" name="book_name" id="book_name">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    let id = '';
    $('#stu_id, #book_id').on('focus', function() {
        id = $(this).prop('id');
        console.log(id);
    }).on('blur', function() {
        // ajax code
        console.log('ajax code executed with ' + id);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `id` of the input where user was typing, you can use **[`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)** with `on("input", callback)`, your code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $($("input[type='text']")).on("input", function() {
      $(this).blur(function() {
         // ajax code
      });
  });
});
```

**Note:**

- Writing `$().blur()` in your `if` condition is completely wrong, it will trigger the `blur`event on the element rather than checking over it.
- Note that if you don't have more code to write inside the first `on("input")` callback, it will be irrelevant to use it just for taking the current element with `$(this)` then using it for the `blur()` event binding.

You can directly write:

```
$("input[type='text']").blur(function() {
    // ajax code
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $($("input[type='text']")).on("input", function() {
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    console.log(id);
    $(this).blur(function() {
      // ajax code
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stu_id" id="stu_id">
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="stu_name">
<input type="text" name="book_id" id="book_id">
<input type="text" name="book_name" id="book_name">
```

Comment: the id used in your blur handler will always be undefined. see this post - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383460/how-to-get-jquery-selector-from-event-handler)

Comment: Oh my bad, how can I miss such a thing, I was only thinking about scopes, @UdoE.thank you for pointing it out.