# How to get jquery selector from event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several input elements on a page and one of them (the first one) is where I can enter in a specific id of any of the other elements.

I want my code set up in such a way that when i focus on any of the other elements and its id matches the text that was entered in the first element, it is highlighted and a text indicating i selected the correct element is displayed within it.

I use the text entered in the first input element to form the id that I am looking for.

So far this is what i have.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var selector; 
     
     $('#selector').on('input', function() {
         selector = $(this).val();
     });
     $('#' + selector).on('focus', function() {
         if ($(this).is('#' + selector)) {
             $(this).val("that's me: " + selector).css('border', 'solid red 1px');
         }
     }).on('blur', function() {
         $(this).val('').css('border', 'solid #555 1px');
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='selector' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target1' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target2' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target3' type='text' /><br />
```

After entering the id of anyone of the target input elements in the first input, I set the "selector" value. However, my focus handler seems not to be firing for any of the other input elements and no error is reported on the console. What could be the problem.

Comment: You can't use `$('#' + selector)` until the event occurs to define `selector`. Right now your code is evaluating as `$('#' + undefined)` and only runs on page load. This seems like a strange UI...what is your actual use case?

Comment: @charlietfl, assuming the ids are generated programmatically, and tagets are search results from a sever query. i could associate the search string some how with the target ids and for instance locate best search result.

Comment: OK but those wouldn't be in `<input>` would they? And how would you know the `id` to type in? Whole thing still seems very strange to me

Comment: definitely not, i had to use the target input tags for clarity. but the first input tag is essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$('#' +selector)` use `$('input[id^=target]')` (or add a common class) and your other logic remains the same

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var selector; 
     
     $('#selector').on('input', function() {
         selector = $(this).val();
     });

     $('input[id^=target]').on('focus', function() {
         if ($(this).is('#' + selector)) {
             $(this).val("that's me: " + selector).css('border', 'solid red 1px');
         }
     }).on('blur', function() {
         $(this).val('').css('border', 'solid #555 1px');
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='selector' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target1' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target2' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target3' type='text' /><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

charlietfl is right. You have to define `selector` first. So, by simply placing the focus and blur functions within the input function, it works *only* when the selector is defined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var selector; 

    
  $('#selector').on('input', function() {    
    selector  = $(this).val();

    $('#' + selector).on('focus', function() {
      if ($(this).is('#' + selector)) {    
        $(this).val("that's me: " + selector).css('border', 'solid red 1px');
      }  
    }).on('blur', function() {
      $(this).val('').css('border', 'solid #555 1px');
    });  
    
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='selector' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target1' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target2' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target3' type='text' /><br />
```

Comment: Problem with this whole concept is it can add numerous listeners if edits are made

Comment: i see that. the focus and blur events will be attached on each input. Is there a way of removing listeners before reattaching?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your event at the start with `undefined` value and it's not being changed anymore. You have to create eventListener after input when you have value in your variable.

**Don't forget to unbind old listeners**

On each input you should use jQuery `unbind` to unbind your previous listener so it will not keep stacking up and **don't forget to check if element exists**.

> The **unbind()** method was deprecated in version 3.0. Use the **off()** method instead. You can read more about off() [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp).

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
var selector;
var $element;
var $newElement;

$('#selector').on('input', function() {
    selector = $(this).val();
    $newElement = $('#' + selector);
    if ($newElement) {
        if ($element) $element.off();
        $element = $newElement;
        $element.on('focus', function() {
            if ($(this).is('#' + selector)) {
                $(this).val("that's me: " + selector).css('border', 'solid red 1px');
            }
        }).on('blur', function() {
            $(this).val('').css('border', 'solid #555 1px');
        });
    }
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='selector' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target1' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target2' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target3' type='text' /><br />
```

Comment: Why all the highlighted information about deprecated method when it isn't relevant to OP's code? Also `off()` with no arguments is not right. The eventName(s) is/are required

Comment: Also `if ($newElement)` will ***always*** be truthy since `$(selector)` always returns an object regardless if selector match found or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to attach `on focus` + `on blur` handlers once, at the start of the program, when `selector` is still `undefined`:

```
$('#' + selector).on('focus', function() {
```

What you need to do instead is re-attach the handlers whenever the `#selector` changes (and also make sure to un-attach the previous handlers):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var elem; 
     
     $('#selector').on('input', function() {
         if (elem) {
             elem.off('focus');
             elem.off('blur');
         }
         elem = $('#' + $(this).val());
         elem.on('focus', function () {
             $(this).val("that's me: " + selector).css('border', 'solid red 1px');
         });
         elem.on('blur', function () {
             $(this).val('').css('border', '');
         });
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='selector' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target1' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target2' type='text' /><br />
<input id='target3' type='text' /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like charlietfl commented on your question. You are setting the focus event listener to a selector that has not gotten a value yet. `$('#' + selector)` has no result at initialization, so nothing will happen.

Most of your code is good, but the problem is in the selecting the inputs after the `<input id="#selector" type="text"/>` element.

You'll want to set the event listeners to all of the inputs, except maybe the first one, and listen for their focusses and blurs.

```
$('input:not(#selector)').on('focus', function() {
  if ($(this).is('#' + selector)) {    
    $(this).val("that's me: " + selector).css('border', 'solid red 1px');
  }  
}).on('blur', function() {
  $(this).val('').css('border', 'solid #555 1px');
});
```

Now you can freely change the selector variable and check it each time when a user focusses on the all of the inputs but the first.

**Edit:** This is one of my first comments here on stackoverflow and I'm trying to learn from it. If this is wrong, then could somebody help me out in explaning why. Thanks!